# Y labels are not shown fully when using setVisibleYRangeMinimum in ios Charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I'm using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts and having troubles getting setVisibleYRangeMinimum to work properly. I expect it not only to zoom out to minimum range but also to display all the labels on Y axis.

Here's my code snippet:

```
data.addDataSet(set1)
wrapperGraphView.data = data
wrapperGraphView.setVisibleYRangeMinimum(300, axis: .left)
wrapperGraphView.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Here's the result:
[image: result]

It's zooming out properly, but does not display all the labels up to 300 on Y axis.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As per Charts default property it will hide Top label as its out of bounds of Charts bounds.

To force enable your max value you need to enable below property to show top label.

```
wrapperGraphView.leftAxis.forceLabelsEnabled = true
```

Hope this will help you to get top label in your chart.